# What is the correct way to buffer channels to not block when inserting from a select? Is doing it in a goroutine an antipattern

Tags: go

For example if I had select statement like this:

```
ch1 := make(chan string, 1)
ch2 := make(chan string, 1)

ch1 <- "hi"
ch2 <- "bye"

select {
case msg := <-ch1:
    if msg == "hi":
        ch2 <- msg
case <-ch2:
    // do something
}
```

There's a chance that this will lock since there is already a string in `ch2`. I'm assuming this is an antipattern:

```
ch1 := make(chan string, 1)
ch2 := make(chan string, 1)

ch1 <- "hi"
ch2 <- "bye"

select {
case msg := <-ch1:
    if msg == "hi":
        go func() {ch2 <- msg}()
case <-ch2:
    // do something
}
```

Obviously this is somewhat contrived but I have a similar situation where in my main thread there is a select statement on n channels and other processes add items to those channels.

Comment: In this example, use `if msg == "hi" { /* do something */ }}` where `do something` is the same as the code in the `<-ch2` case.

Comment: I would consider the first version more an "antipattern": In general any goroutine should either read from or write to a channel as this makes reasoning about what happens much more simple.

Comment: I don't see why the second example would be an antipattern since you lock the go routine. That looks ok to me. It will resume execution once the first string in `ch2` is read.

Comment: If you're worried this "edge" case would happen too often - thus creating a go-routine each time - create a long-lived go-routine to handle these events.